# How do I convert data from a Scikit-learn Bunch object to a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have used the following code to convert the sk learn breast cancer data set to data frame : I am not getting the output ? I am very new in python and not able to figure out what is wrong.

```
def answer_one(): 

    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer 
    cancer = load_breast_cancer()     
    data = numpy.c_[cancer.data, cancer.target]
    columns = numpy.append(cancer.feature_names, ["target"])
    return pandas.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

answer_one()
```

Answer (score 8):

Use pandas

There was a great answer here: [How to convert a Scikit-learn dataset to a Pandas dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38105539/how-to-convert-a-scikit-learn-dataset-to-a-pandas-dataset/46379878#46379878)

The keys in bunch object give you an idea about which data you want to make columns for.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(cancer.data, columns=cancer.feature_names)
df['target'] = pd.Series(cancer.target)
```

Answer (score 8):

As of scikit-learn 0.23 you can do the following to get a DataFrame and save some keystrokes:

```
df = load_breast_cancer(as_frame=True)
df.frame
```

Comment: Not working for me for some reason in Google Colab. Colab has 0.22, but I upgraded to 0.24 using pip (and the __version__ shows the updated version), still using as_frame=True) still returns a bunch :-/

Comment: Question: How did you know to use the attribute `.frame`? I'm new to Python and sklearn and trying to figure out how you knew to use `.frame`, as I don't see it mentioned in the help docs.

Comment: @Desmond, see example here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_iris.html  "dataBunch
Dictionary-like object, with the following attributes.

data{ndarray, dataframe} of shape (150, 4)
The data matrix. If as_frame=True, data will be a pandas DataFrame.
...
frame: DataFrame of shape (150, 5)
Only present when as_frame=True. DataFrame with data and target.

Answer (score 6):

The following code works

```
def answer_one(): 
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer 
    cancer = load_breast_cancer()     
    data = np.c_[cancer.data, cancer.target]
    columns = np.append(cancer.feature_names, ["target"])
    return pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

answer_one()
```

The reason why your code doesn't work before was you try to call `numpy` and `pandas` package again after defining it as `np` and `pd` respectively.

However, i suggest that the package loading and redefinition is done at the beginning of the script, outside a function definition.

Comment: def answer_one():   
    
 
     
    data = numpy.c_[cancer.data, cancer.target]
    columns = numpy.append(cancer.feature_names, ["target"])
    return pandas.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
    answer_one()

Comment: I tried without defining them. but does  not get an output. Anything wrong with the return statement ?

Answer (score 3):

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data=cancer.data, columns=cancer.feature_names)
dataframe['target'] = cancer.target
return dataframe
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please include a brief description of how this code solves the problem.