# How can we convert a DataFrame in to Bunch data type?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

We have different data-sets available in scikit-learn (eg., Iris data-sets). Iris data-set is a bunch data type. So how can we convert a DataFrame in to a Bunch data type?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more why do you want to convert a DataFrame into a Bunch Datatype? We are usually interested in converting bunch to DataFrame, for which you can find the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38105539/how-to-convert-a-scikit-learn-dataset-to-a-pandas-dataset

Comment: I was playing with MNIST data set it is easy when it is bunch type.

Answer (score 2):

> So how can we convert a DataFrame in to a Bunch data type?

First, you can convert the dataframe into a dict using the pandas function [to_dict()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html).

Then, using the library Bunch, you can convert the dict into an object Bunch. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24852544/5963546) provides a really good example of how to do it.