# How do I convert this scikit-learn section to pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, iris-dataset

I am trying to convert this Python code section to pandas dataframe:

```
iris = datasets.load_iris()
x = iris.data
y = iris.target
```

I will like to import [Iris data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t30njed9l1l1xn5/Iris.csv?dl=0) on my local machine instead of loading the data from Scikit library. Your kind suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a Scikit-learn dataset to a Pandas dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38105539/how-to-convert-a-scikit-learn-dataset-to-a-pandas-dataset). Also, see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: Not really, my problem requires the steps in these links reversed. I have tried them all out with no success thus far. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use from_records and concat to create a datafram. then rename the columns:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame.from_records(x),pd.DataFrame(y)],axis=1)
df.columns = ['col1','col2','col3','col4','target']
```

Comment: I need some explanations on your kind answer. Thanks

Comment: I created a data frame from x np array and a data frame from y array. then using pandas. concat function contacted them together with columns (axis=1).

Comment: your code worked perfectly for Scikit to pd dataframe but I am trying to move from pd dataframe to Scikit! Your kind suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Simply select the 
X = df.iloc[:,:n-1]
y = df[['target']]
And you can use train_test_split to split to train and test sets