# Making a sns.pairplot using scikit wine dataset

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, seaborn

This seems simple enough, but I can't find a solution online.

I am trying to create an sns.pairplot in Python. I have downloaded the wine dataset, kept the features that I need, and run the plot.

```
%matplotlib inline

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from sklearn.datasets import load_wine

# Load the wine dataset
wine = datasets.load_wine()
wine = list(zip(wine.data, wine.target))

wine = load_wine()
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
wine = load_wine
data = load_wine()
df = pd.DataFrame(data.data, columns=data.feature_names)

#This is the code that should run the plot
b=sns.pairplot(df, vars = df.columns[1 :], hue = "target", height = 2.5)
```

But I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2894             try:
-> 2895                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2896             except KeyError as err:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'target'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-108-1107acc27949> in <module>
----> 1 b=sns.pairplot(df, vars = df.columns[1 :], hue = "target", height = 2.5)
      2 
      3 plt.show()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\_decorators.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     44             )
     45         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 46         return f(**kwargs)
     47     return inner_f
     48 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\axisgrid.py in pairplot(data, hue, hue_order, palette, vars, x_vars, y_vars, kind, diag_kind, markers, height, aspect, corner, dropna, plot_kws, diag_kws, grid_kws, size)
   1923     # Set up the PairGrid
   1924     grid_kws.setdefault("diag_sharey", diag_kind == "hist")
-> 1925     grid = PairGrid(data, vars=vars, x_vars=x_vars, y_vars=y_vars, hue=hue,
   1926                     hue_order=hue_order, palette=palette, corner=corner,
   1927                     height=height, aspect=aspect, dropna=dropna, **grid_kws)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\_decorators.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     44             )
     45         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 46         return f(**kwargs)
     47     return inner_f
     48 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\axisgrid.py in __init__(self, data, hue, hue_order, palette, hue_kws, vars, x_vars, y_vars, corner, diag_sharey, height, aspect, layout_pad, despine, dropna, size)
   1212                                       index=data.index)
   1213         else:
-> 1214             hue_names = categorical_order(data[hue], hue_order)
   1215             if dropna:
   1216                 # Filter NA from the list of unique hue names

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2900             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2901                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2902             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2903             if is_integer(indexer):
   2904                 indexer = [indexer]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2895                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2896             except KeyError as err:
-> 2897                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   2898 
   2899         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 'target'
```

The solution linked to this question: [How to convert a Scikit-learn dataset to a Pandas dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38105539/how-to-convert-a-scikit-learn-dataset-to-a-pandas-dataset) unfortunately doesn't seem to work here.

I also tried 'class' instead of target. Could it be that the 'zip' function isn't working correctly above, so the program can't identify 'target'?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

From what you typed it works like this.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
wine = load_wine
data = load_wine()
df = pd.DataFrame(data.data, columns=data.feature_names)

#This is the code that should run the plot
b=sns.pairplot(df, vars = df.columns[1 :], height = 2.5)
```

[image: pairplot]

The question is how do you want to highlight features and why?
You cut alcohol from the list so the target simply won't be aligned.
Second thing is that it's feature wise pairplot not target/class.
So all in all I don't understand what you are trying to do here